# What type of certificate do you need in iOS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am new in iOS development & I have couple of common questions about the certification of  `developer.apple`. I want to create a certificate for my MAC (from where I will develop my applications using **xcode 5**) from my newly created `developer.apple` account. I followed some of tutorials about it, but all of them are in OLD  INTERFACE. They have less option in the time of creating certificate. But, now when i go to my account, I see some more option then the tutorials. I don't have enough knowledge about iOS certification. So, after clicking "+" button, in "certificates" section (from left panel), I find these options :

[image]

Now, if I want to create a certificate for both "Development & Production" I think I should select 
"iOS App Development" from "Development" section & go through it and as well as "App Store and Ad Hoc" from "Production" section. But my question is, if my application is about push notification & I select these two option for creating certificate, is these two certificate allow that??

If any one can describe about the other options besides these two (when should I select those at the time of making certificates), that will be more appreciable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1), explained everything you need.

You can create certificate using "iOS App Development" but you need to enable the push notification services while creating the APP ID and also need to generate the push notification SSL certificate.
You can create push notification SSL from either way, it is same. You can read the Apple's Documentation here, for more understanding : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I already see this tutorials. That means if i want to use "PUSH NOTIFICATION SERVICE" in my app, i can't use normal "iOS App Development" option, right??? I have to choose "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)" & in Production section Notification service SSL (Production).

Comment: You can create certificate using "iOS App Development" but you need to enable the push notification services while creating the APP ID and also need to generate the push notification SSL certificate.

Comment: Ok, i got it. But, if i do that through app ID creation, then what is the use of "PUSH NOTIFICATION SERVICE" here?????
Thanks.

Comment: You can create push notification SSL from either way, it is same.

Comment: You can read the Apple's Documentation here, for more understanding : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1

Comment: ok, i am going to read the documentation. One last thing. If i check the "Push Notification enable" option at the time of creating app ID, does the app be listed in the "setting page>>Notification Center List"?

Comment: For that, you need to write the code in the AppDelegate to generate device token, which you will use to send the push notification to your device from server.

Answer (score 4):

About the first option "Development", you have two options because you have to create 2 different certificates if you want to handle push notification.
This tutorial using the API Urban Air Ship explain everything about the certificate for push notification : [Urban Air Ship iOS Certificate](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/ios.html#set-up-your-application-with-apple)

It is the same mechanisms for the production, it's why there is still 2 certificates needed.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @Pull. It seems a resourceful tutorials. I will look after it.

Comment: Handling push notification with the kind of API is really simple and free until about 100 000 pushs... I recommend it. Take a look at the link, it explain how handle the certificate iOS for the push notification needed for the "Apple PUsh Notification service SSL'

Comment: yes, i was used "parser.com" for sending push. But, unfortunately, i have to do it by own coding, cause the push will use for a complex purpose in an application :(

Comment: If you have to redo the coding good luck indeed... But still the link with Urban Air Ship about the certificate is still the same, you will have to do the exact same step with Appel certificate